# angularjs onload click on table column field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have problem with clicking on row element field when go to edit page.
On edit page i have table, on every name in table I added id that is actualy ID of that row data

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in $data" ng-class="{clicked: row._id == rowClicked}"">
   <td data-title="'Name' | translate" sortable="'name'" id="{{row._id}}"
       ng-click="populateDivisionServices(row)" 
      class="nameCursor">
      {{row.name | ci18n}}
   </td>
```

onload edit page i put this

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
  $timeout(function() {
    angular.element(document.getElementById($scope.division._id)).triggerHandler('click');
  }, 0);
});
```

or

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
  $timeout(function() {
    angular.element(document.getElementById($scope.division._id)).triggerHandler('click');
  }, 500);
});
```

or

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
    angular.element(document.getElementById($scope.division._id)).triggerHandler('click');
});
```

but nothing does not work, i debugg through console and it go to this function but it does not click on this name, because when it click on name it should be highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply call the function from the controller:

```
var row = $scope.$data.find(_ => _._id == $scope.division._id);
$scope.populateDivisionServices(row);
```

No need to use `.triggerHandler` to invoke the function.